# How to ask user to reauthenticate for sensitive operation in a SPFX webpart?

Tags: spfx, authentication, msal

I'm building a SPFX webpart that perform some sensitive operation when a button is clicked (document approbation for example).

Is there any way to ask the user to reauthenticate to "sign" the action ?

The user flow is similar to the account security behavior. When you want to check/change your security options, you are forced to reauthenticate.

Using MSAL, we may trigger a new account prompt but using SFPX, is it possible without loosing the initial context?